# How can I make responsive UI using stack and positioned with x y coordinates?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, flutter-layout

I am using stack and positioned with x y coordinates from gesturedetector, ontapdowndetils(details),in with details provide localposition.

But by positioning it with x y , it is not responsive as I tried to do it with stack overflow answered questions and tips. Its changing position from device to device. please refer images and code provided , need to position it on same spots on all devices.

[image]
[image]

```
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyHomePage({super.key});

    @override
    State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    int selectedImageIndex = 0;
    String ourImage = '';

    void _changeImageIndex(index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedImageIndex = index;
    });
    }

    addImageToSpots() {
    setState(() {
      ourImage =
          'https://img.ecelebrityfacts.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08
           /elon-musk-3067-30988-1471258987-2048x2048.jpg';
     });
     }

     List<ImageList> list = [
      ImageList(
      image:
          'https://www.101planners.com/borders/wp-content/uploads/2018/03
           /wanted-poster-13.jpg',
      x: 1650.0,
      y: 1229.0502793296089,
      ),
      ImageList(
      image: 'https://img1.etsystatic.com/000/0/6713244/il_570xN.306337089.jpg',
      x: 99.35715553977273,
      y: 291.88920454545456,
      ),
      ];

      var newX;
      var newY;
 
      void setPoints() async {
      if (mounted) {
       setState(() {
        var newWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        var newHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .6;
        double baseWidth = 395;
        double baseHeight = 460;
        newX = (newWidth * 102) / baseWidth;
        newY = (newHeight * 326) / baseHeight;
        });
        }
        }

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        setPoints();
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
         title: const Text('pip image'),
        ),
          body: Center(
          child: Column(
         children: [
          imageSelector(context),
          buildImageList(),
          //buildImageList(),
          ],
          )),
          );
          }

          imageSelector(BuildContext context) {
          var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          return Stack(
         children: [
          SizedBox(
           height: height * .6,
          width: width,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: ((details) {
              print(height);
              print(width);

              print(details
                  .localPosition.dx); // for getting the image local position
              print(details
                  .localPosition.dy); // for getting the image local position
            }),
            child: Image.network(
              list[selectedImageIndex].image,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
          ),
        if (selectedImageIndex == 0)
          Positioned(
            left: newX,
            top: newY,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('addImageToSpots');
                addImageToSpots();
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                height: (height * .6) * .31,
                width: width * .36,
                child: ourImage.isEmpty
                    ? null
                    : Image.network(
                        ourImage,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        else
          Positioned(
            left: newX,
            top: newY,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print('addImageToSpots');
                addImageToSpots();
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: (width * .6) * .19,
                backgroundImage:
                    ourImage.isEmpty ? null : NetworkImage(ourImage),
              ),
            ),
          )
          ],
        );
        }

      buildImageList() {
       return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 180,
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return imageList(index);
          },
           ),
         ),
       );
       }

       imageList(int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
        print(index);
        _changeImageIndex(index);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          child: Image.network(
            list[index].image,
            width: 150,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
         ),
         ),
         );
        }
       }
```

Comment: As it seems, you're trying to make those circles click-able, you should rely on transparent click zones over a colored graphic instead of colored circular widgets, as with any screen size, it won't affect the responsiveness as well as the layout.

Comment: I can help further if you can tell me the purpose of doing it, what do you want to achieve?